# Can you display a number from a Report onto a MS Access Button

Tags: ms-access-2013

Is it possible to display a count number from a report onto a button

Comment: can you please elaborate more..

Comment: Id like to display the number of names I have in a report to show on an MS Access button

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You could control this from the report:

```
Forms!YourForm!YourButton.Caption = Count([FieldToCountInYourReport])
```